# Android : How to call the first activity in the ActivityGroup when I click the same tab again?

Tags: android, tabs

I am using a tab application in which I am using ActivtyGroup to embedded many views. If I click the same tab after swiching between many views, I cannot view the first activity in the activity group. It remains in the activity that I am currently focusing.

How can I go back to first activity or call the setContent() method of TabHost?

Thank you..

Comment: Adding .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) will fulfill your requirement.

Like This : `tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3")
            .setIndicator("destroy")
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Controls2.class)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));
`

Comment: addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) will work fine, if I click my tab from other tab. I want to start the first activity when I click from the curent tab iteself

Comment: Bear in mind that activity groups are being phased out in favor of fragments, so you may wish to consider revising your implementation.

Comment: hi can anyone help me out am facing one issue  here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223444/current-acivity-should-replaced-with-previous-activity-back